# Limit SQL query results by distinct column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have an table with columns `id`, `score`, `parent_id` ordered by the `score`.

| id | score | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5859 | 10 | 5859 |
| 2157043 | 9 | 5859 |
| 21064154 | 8 | 21064154 |
| 51992 | 7 | 51992 |
| 34384599 | 6 | 51992 |
| 1675761 | 5 | 1675761 |
| 3465729 | 4 | 3465729 |
| 401202 | 3 | 401203 |
| 1817458 | 2 | 1817458 |

I want to query all columns from this table with the same order but limit results at least 5 rows to meet the unique parent_id number equal to 5. As result, the parent_id only contains 5 ids: 5859, 21064154, 51992, 1675761, 3465729

Expected Results like:

| id | score | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5859 | 10 | 5859 |
| 2157043 | 9 | 5859 |
| 21064154 | 8 | 21064154 |
| 51992 | 7 | 51992 |
| 34384599 | 6 | 51992 |
| 1675761 | 5 | 1675761 |
| 3465729 | 4 | 3465729 |

Comment: Please do not [delete & repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75062261/3404097) questions, edit them per feedback.

Comment: Again: "limit results at least 5 rows" means 5 or more so why do you say "limit" & why can't returning all rows or any number "more" satisfy the specification & what if there are fewer than 5 to be returned? Do you mean "at most"? This is not clear. Also it is not clear what your example output has to do with the specifictaion. [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other way you could accomplish this is to use *lag* to indicate when the id changes and then use a *cumulative sum* over a window then filtering accordingly:

```
select id, score, parent_id
from (
  select *, Sum(diff) over(order by score desc)seq
  from (
     select *, 
       case when Lag(parent_id) over(order by score desc) = parent_id then 0 else 1 end diff
    from t
  )t
)d
where seq <= 5
order by score desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to retain rows that belong to the top 5 scoring `parent_id`s.

Although a sophisticated approach based on window functions might be possible here, here is one way to do it simply using a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
where parent_id in (
    select top 5 parent_id 
    from mytable 
    group by parent_id 
    order by max(score) desc
)
order by score desc
```

If your data may have some score tied, consider adding option `with ties` to the subquery in order to guarantee a predictable result.