# Expand on limit SQL query results use lag() window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, row-number

I have an table with columns `id`, `score`, `parent_id` ordered by the `score`. I have ask one scenario in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75063807/limit-sql-query-results-by-distinct-column-value).

The different from previous question is that the parent_id might show up on multiple rows not necessary sequence rows. The updated table:

| id | score | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5859 | 10 | 5859 |
| 2157043 | 9 | 5859 |
| 21064154 | 8 | 21064154 |
| 51992 | 7 | 51992 |
| 34384599 | 6 | 51992 |
| 1675761 | 5 | 5859 |
| 3465729 | 4 | 3465729 |
| 401202 | 3 | 401203 |
| 1817458 | 2 | 1817458 |

I want to query all columns from this table with the same order but limit results at least 5 rows to meet the unique parent_id number equal to 5. As result, the parent_id only contains 5 ids: 5859, 21064154, 51992, 3465729, 401203

Expected Results like:

| id | score | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5859 | 10 | 5859 |
| 2157043 | 9 | 5859 |
| 21064154 | 8 | 21064154 |
| 51992 | 7 | 51992 |
| 34384599 | 6 | 51992 |
| 1675761 | 5 | 5859 |
| 3465729 | 4 | 3465729 |
| 401202 | 3 | 401203 |

The solution using `lag` only works for the following row has same value of parent_id. If use Java, we could use a SET to store the parent_id and keep count the unique parent_id, but how do we write in SQL?

```
select id, score, parent_id
from (
  select *, Sum(diff) over(order by score desc)seq
  from (
     select *, 
       case when Lag(parent_id) over(order by score desc) = parent_id then 0 else 1 end diff
    from t
  )t
)d
where seq <= 5
order by score desc;
```

Comment: This statement "I want to query all columns from this table with the same order but limit results at least 5 rows to meet the unique parent_id number equal to 5" makes no sense.  None of these examples have a value of 5 -- what do you actually mean?

Comment: it's retrieving all the rows in order of score until 5 unique values of `parent_id` have been returned, so the desired results are rows with score 10 to 3, where at 3, there are 5 unique values of `parent_id` - nothing to do with them having a value of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you, a refactor of your existing query but an alternative to *lag* using *exists* which caters for non-sequential rows, give this a try:

```
select id, score, parent_id
from (
  select *, Sum(keep) over (order by score desc) seq
  from (
    select *, 
      case when exists (
        select * from t t2 
        where t2.parent_id = t.parent_id and t2.score > t.score
      ) then 0 else 1 end keep
      from t
  )t
)s
where seq <= 5
order by score desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method to consider might be:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t t1
WHERE
 (SELECT count(distinct parent_id)
 FROM t t2
 WHERE t2.score >= t1.score) <= 5
```

You can see [a Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hS0ms6s1). The `WHERE` clause is simply counting the number of distinct `parent_id`s with a `score` >= the current row.